# Collect all Classes with Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to read all Classes from my Project in a Array? I heard something from Reflection, but i haven't found a way yet. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Check this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-java-method-at-runtime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) project - it allows for example to searching for sub-classes or classes with given annotation.

Answer (score 0):

See this

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.somepackage.TestClass");
```